# c++ - Euler Project - Level 03

Tags: c++

I'm going through the level 03' euler project. 
Here is my code and I still dont understand why it doesnt work. 
Is it a mathematics Problem? 
There is a compilation but the result is false. There are all of a number's factors, and not only the primes..
Could someone have a look on it?
Thanks
BR

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <vector>
    #include <cmath>
    #include <cstdint>
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void facteursden(std::vector<uint64_t>& facteursden, uint64_t number)
{

    uint64_t i = 2;

    for (i = 1; i <= number; ++i) {
        if (number % i == 0) {
            facteursden.push_back(i);
        }
    }
}
//////////////////////////////////////////////
uint64_t factprem(uint64_t n)
{
    uint64_t i = 1;

    for (i = 1; i*i < n; ++i) {
   if (n % i != 0)
 return 1; }
return 0; 
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int main()
{

    std::vector<uint64_t> monTableau1;
    facteursden(monTableau1, 49);
uint64_t i = 0;
for (i = 0; i < (uint64_t)monTableau1.size(); ++i) {
if (factprem(monTableau1[i]) == 1) {
std::cout << monTableau1[i] << std::endl; }}

return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: You don't even say what problem is your code supposed to solve. I mean, what is that level 3 Euler about? Also, what's wrong with it? Are you getting any errors? Which ones? Please include them in the question.

Comment: Sorry, here is the euler problem: "The prime factors of 13195 are 5, 7, 13 and 29.

What is the largest prime factor of the number 600851475143 ?" My problem is actually, I have all factors, my code doesnt select the primes.

Comment: Project Euler is for learning.  It doesn't really help to have solutions all over the place.  You can still ask a specific question about something that you're stuck at.

Comment: I know the mathematic solution but i have a problem in my second function. I would like, by this function, to only keep primes number, but when i execute my function, all the factors are couted. I cant find my mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two mistakes in

```
uint64_t factprem(uint64_t n)
```

1. In for loop start from

```
i=2
```

instead of i=1

2.Function should look like this

```
uint64_t factprem(uint64_t n)
{
uint64_t i = 1;

for (i = 2; i*i <=n; ++i) {
   if (n % i == 0)
 return 0; }
return 1;
}
```

Comment: In function it is checking if i is a divisor of n, if i=1 then i is a divisor of n (for any n because 1 is every number's divisor)and it will show n is not prime whereas it is. If you got it dont forget to mark as answer.